# Login form validation in Yii framework with my sql database

Tags: forms, validation, yii

I am new in yii framework but have little bit knowlwdge about yii.
I want to validate my login form with database.
If match UserName(input)=UserName(db) and also password then Echo Message "Success" else "Error".

Keep in mind. I am new in Yii not advance member.

What Code should we write in:

-> Form

-> Controller
-> Model

Comment: Larry Ullman has a good post on this subject: http://www.larryullman.com/2010/01/07/custom-authentication-using-the-yii-framework/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this documentation by Yii about login forms and go through the whole detailed process, hope this helps: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model

Comment: Thanks for your comments but still need more help

Answer (score 1):

Please go with some user authentication on demo application like [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/prototype.auth) , which is an example of yii official blog demo, included with yii framework download .